# Don't know the right way to import taskrouter.js into react

Tags: reactjs, twilio

I trying to import [taskrouter.js](http://media.twiliocdn.com/taskrouter/js/v1.20/taskrouter.js) into my react app, and I dont know the right way to do it.

```
 const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "../library/taskrouter.js";
    script.async = true;
    document.body.appendChild(script)
    script.onload = function() {
        axios.get(url_host + '/worker/activiti')
        .then((res) => {
            var worker = new Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker(res);
            console.log("YEET",worker)
        })
      };
```

This is the error that I get.

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'Worker' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First of all, have you confirmed that loading the script like that does actually include the TaskRouter JS file on your page? I'd be concerned that webpack (or whatever you are using to build your application) might do something unexpected with the script src you're setting there. Or may not ultimately refer to the correct file after the project is built.

I would try one of two things to include TaskRouter.js. Either include the TaskRouter.js file from the CDN outside of React's control over the application, in the `<head>` of your index.html file.

```
<script src="//media.twiliocdn.com/taskrouter/js/v1.13/taskrouter.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, there is an [npm package now available for TaskRouter JS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio-taskrouter). Use it by installing into your project:

```
npm install twilio-taskrouter --save
```

You can then use the worker from React by importing it like so:

```
import { Worker } from 'twilio-taskrouter';
```

You can then instantiate a new worker using:

```
const worker = new Worker(token);
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: hey Phil sorry for bing this up, I imported  { WORKER } like u told me to, and then using  var worker = new Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker(WORKER_TOKEN), but i still got the error like before.

Comment: Because you imported `Worker` you now don't need to use `Twilio.TaskRouter.Worker`, in fact that doesn't exist. You can use the class you imported, so call `new Worker(WORKER_TOKEN)`.

Comment: Thx you, It work but now i get this error https://i.imgur.com/KxSBPyw.png can u take a look at it for me a, many thanks.

Comment: You got a 403 (Forbidden) error, which likely means there is something wrong with your access token. Check it over against [the TaskRouter JS access token documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/js-sdk/workspace/worker#capability-token) and if you can't find what's wrong I'd recommend asking a new question as this will be hard to deal with in the comments.